# Simple assembly math calculation

Tags: math, assembly

Hello I'm trying to calculate simple math function (2c-a)/(c+ax). But for some reason all my answers are 0.
Given: a - b, b - w, c - w, x - w, y - b

```
MOV ax, 2
MUL c    ; dx:ax=2c
JC kl1  ; sandauga netilpo i ax
XCHG ax, dx
MOV al, a
XOR ah, ah
ADD dx, ax    ; c^2-a
JC kl1
MOV al, a
MUL x[si] ; a*x 
JC kl1  ; sandauga netilpo i ax
ADD bx, ax    ; ax+c
JC kl1
CMP al, 0
JE kl2    ; dalyba is 0
MOV ax, dx
XOR dx, dx
DIV bx    ; ax=rez
re:
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Is this x86 assembler? You should tag your question with the appropriate processor and/or instruction set.

Comment: Use a debugger to single step your program and see where it goes wrong. For starters, `ADD dx, ax` doesn't look like calculating `-a` more like `+a`. Then `MUL x[si]` destroys `dx` where you had your result (unless it's a byte sized multiplication). Also we don't know what `x[si]` is, no mention of that in your question. You then do `ADD bx, ax` without `bx` being loaded with anything.

Answer (score 0):

follow this example so you have short problem when occurred an error
expression = (2*c-a)/(c+a*x)

mov ax,c ; load ax with variable c

shl ax,1 ; multiplay c*2

sub ax,a ; 2c - a

mov parte1,ax ; store result

mov ax,a ; load ax with variable a

mov bx,x ; load bx with variable x

mul bx   ; ax = a per x

add ax,c ; c+ax

mov parte2,ax ;store result

push ax ; preserve last calcolus second operand of expression

mov ax,parte1 ;load ax with variable parte1 that is first operand of 
expression

pop bx ; load bx with variable parte2 that is second operand of expression

div bx ; risultato = parte1 / parte2 = ax:dx

ax = int part
dx = rest

i hope to hel you.